# TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...(0,_reactNavigationStack.createDrawerNavigator)

Tags: react-native

I recently updated my react-native app and I am experiencing this error. I fail to understand what's wrong with the code.

```html
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createStackNavigator,
  createSwitchNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation-stack';

// app stack
const appNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    splashScreen: {
      screen: SplashScreen,
    },
    public: {
      screen: publicRoutes,
    },
    private: {
      screen: createDrawerNavigator(
        {
          home: privateRoutes,
        },
        {
          contentComponent: DrawerMenu,
          overlayColor: colors.overlayColor,
        },
      ),
    },
    tnc: {
      screen: TermsAndConditions,
    },
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
    navigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: false,
    },
  },
);
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to import createDrawerNavigator from 'react-navigation-stack'.
You should do this instead:

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
```

Read more about drawer navigator here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/

Comment: Thank you. It worked. And I am getting the same error now for "createSwitchNavigator". Do I install @react-navigation/switch for it?

Comment: Actually you don't need SwitchNavigator anymore because the navigation supports routes changes on the flight now so you can just use `if` instead: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow